# Symfony 4 Functional Form Test with CSRF Token and Session

Tags: php, symfony, session, phpunit, functional-testing

I am using a symfony 4.4 with the form bundle and want to make some functional tests.

My form has multiple steps and I want to perform a complete form until the success message. But with `csrf_protection:true` I can't even get to page 2. If I disable it for the test environment I can get to page 2. If I dump my session at page 2, I can see, that it is empty. Here is an example of my test:

```php
$client = static::createClient();
$client->request('GET', '/test');
$crawler = $client->submitForm('Next', ['name' => 'Max Mustermann']); // => lands on step2
$crawler = $client->submitForm('Next', ['email' => 'asdf@ase.de']); // => lands back on step 1 with emtpy form. So session is empty
```

Does anyone have an idea what is wrong here?
This page says, that is have to work, but it doesn't.
https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/components/http_foundation/session_testing.html#functional-testing

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to retrieve the form from the client's response then submit the form with the data, as example:

```
// Get the crawler
$crawler = $client->request('GET', '/test');

// Get the form
$form = $crawler->filter('form')->form();

// Fill the form. NB: double check your form structure/fields name
$form['name'] = 'Max Mustermann';
$form['email'] = 'asdf@ase.de';

// Submit the form.
$crawler = $this->client->submit($form);
$this->assertEquals(200, $this->client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but that was my way before. If I change my .env.local to env test and look at it in the frontend, it doesn't work too. So there must be something missing/wrong with the test environment.